# What happened to the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

I'm sure you've seen some of these numbers before:

```
1 3 8 13 21 30 36 45 54 63
```

Whats the next number in the sequence? And what have I done to the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A094110

Comment: @itriedacrab - why aren't you posting that as an answer, seems you've got it?

Comment: @Phylyp I've posted a number sequence question here before, and have since learned my lesson to give those types of questions a wide berth.

Comment: @itriedacrab, you're right. This was such a useless sequence, why does OEIS have it :)? Anyway, I should have checked, but forgot.

Comment: @R.M Did you mean 1,4,8,13,21,30,36,45,54,63  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

every number is the sum of letters (without spaces) of all the previous numbers.

> 3 = one (3 letters)
>   8 = three (5) + one (3)
>   13 = Eight (5) + three (5) + one (3)
>   21 = Thirteen (8) + Eight (5) + three (5) + one (3)
>   30 = twentyOne (9) + 21
>   36 = Thirty (6) + 30
>   and so on....

It's still a Fibonacci series of *count of letters* of n-1th value & number of n-2th value

Comment: But where is the number 1?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov My understanding is that starting with one is simply a convention. Then, if you write it down, the next number will logically be three. See also the link in the comments. Note that I'd say it makes sense to start with zero instead (since there's nothing before it), but that's just my opinion.